# foreign key shows syntax error in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5.3

I have created migration file in that i have written :

```
public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('ad_group', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('campaign_id')->unsigned();
            $table->char('name',32);
        });
        Schema::table('ad_group',function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('campaign_id')->references->('id')->on('campaigns');
        });
    }
```

which returns error like this :

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Your mistake is  "->references->('id')->" must be "->references('id')->"

public function up() {
    Schema::table('ad_group', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->foreign('campaign_id')->references('id')->on('campaigns');
    });
}
```

Hope it help :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a syntax error ! I cannot believe i spent more than 2 hours on this. 

Thank you !

Comment: sometimes it happens ;)

Comment: do not forget mark question as solve )

Comment: Sure. I didn't know how to mark solved. I was trying to upvote your answer!!